# Disable password masking in password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want creating form field hints where the default value shows 'Password' and on focus, it goes away. If the field loses focus with no use input, it will reveal back to the default value of 'Password'.

**Problem:** The default value for the password field gets masked as well. How can I show the default value of 'Password' without getting masked, and masks only the user input?

**jQuery Code**

```
$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").each(function() {
    $(this).val( $(this).attr('title') );
});

$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});

$(".splash_register_short_input, .splash_register_long_input").blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') { // If there is no user input
        $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
        $(this).removeClass('splash_register_have_userinput');
    } else {    // If there is user input
        $(this).addClass('splash_register_have_userinput');
    }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<form id="splash_register_traditional_form">
    <input type="text" name="register_first_name" class="splash_register_short_input" title="First Name" /><label for="register_first_name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="register_last_name" class="splash_register_short_input" title="Last Name" /><label for="register_last_name"></label>
    <input type="text" name="register_email" class="splash_register_long_input" title="Email" /><label for="register_email"></label>
    <input type="password" name="register_password" class="splash_register_long_input" title="Password" /><label for="register_password"></label>
    <input type="submit" id="splash_register_signup_button" value="Sign up" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use the HTML5 `placeholder`-attribute:

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password..." />
```

Concerning the lack of backwards compatibility as mentioned in the comments, [this jQuery placeholder plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/html5-placeholder-password-input) combined with some kind of a fallback machanism in case the attribute is not supported (like maybe [this one](http://unwrongest.com/projects/defaultvalue/)) may be helpful.

Comment: Upvote for standard, simple solution.  However, this isn't backwards compatible at all, so it's not very robust.

Comment: Yea, I think IE10 is *finally* getting around to supporting this most awesome attribute.  Everyone else already has it, sigh..

Comment: That shouldn't matter if you used [labels](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL). A "broken" field is still a far better option than using javascript to implement unmasking a password field.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do it would be to not set default value as value of password field but as an overlay over password field which disappears on focus or when user changes value to something else. You can use the arelady existing jquery in-field-label plugins e.g.

http://www.viget.com/inspire/a-better-jquery-in-field-label-plugin/
http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/
http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/labelify/

Answer (score 0):

To hide password programatically add this line below oncreate android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD, 0);